# Button enabled or disabled when checkbox is checked or not

Tags: javascript, button, checkbox

I have here a code that whenever I checked a checkbox the button will enable but if I unchecked it the button will be disabled. My problem is that, when I add another checkbox the disable and enable of button doesn't work. The output should be whenever I checked one or more checkbox the button will enable but if there's no checkbox that has been checked the button should be disabled. Anyone knows how I can do that?

Here's my code:

```
        <HTML>
            <HEAD> 
            <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

            function Disab(id) 
            {
                if(document.form1.cbox.checked) 
                {
                    document.form1.Button1.disabled=false
                }
                else {
                    document.form1.Button1.disabled=true
                }
            }

            </SCRIPT>

            </HEAD>
            <BODY TEXT="000000" BGCOLOR="FFFFFF">

            <form name="form1">
            <div align="center"> 
            <input name="cbox" type="checkbox" id="cbox2" value="checkbox" onClick=Disab(this.id);>
            Click here to Enable/Disable Button<br /><br />
            <input type=button onClick="alert('Button pressed!')" value="Button" name="Button1" disabled>
            </div>
            </form>
            </BODY>
            </HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that, when I add another checkbox the disable and enable of button doesn't work.

You're trying to enable/disable the button if one or more checkboxes are checked?

```
function verifyChecked() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#myForm input[type='checkbox']");
  var atLeastOneChecked = false;

  for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length && !atLeastOneChecked; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].checked) {
      atLeastOneChecked = true;
    }
  }

  document.form1.Button1.disabled = !atLeastOneChecked;
}
```

Comment: how will I use that code if I add another checkbox?

Comment: The script is looping through all the checkboxes in that form.

Comment: what will be the value of the onClick in my checkbox?

Comment: `<input onclick="verifyChecked()"></input>`

Comment: Read the code an understand it. I didn't write it to work copy-pasted. For example, you have no element with the id `myForm`.